# Linked list declaration in Swift with finger type that can transparently insert in either middle or start

Tags: swift, data-structures

I am attempting to declare a linked list in Swift, with a finger type that is a reference to either a node, allowing to insert or remove beyond that node, or to the linked list itself, in which case inserting or removing at the top of the linked list.

I want to see if this can be made uniform down to the implementation, instead of having to special-case everything: Swift is object-oriented, after all.

I previously had a version which required forced casts, but again I'd like to see if this can be made to work without them (e.g. even if they never end up faulting they still imply runtime checks each time).

I currently have this code:

```
protocol ContainerNodeInterface: class {
    associatedtype ContainedItem;

    var contents: ContainedItem { get };
}

protocol ParentNodeInterface: class {
    associatedtype LinkedItem: ContainerNodeInterface;

    var next: LinkedItem? {get set};
}


class ProtoNode<Contents, NodeType: ParentNodeInterface>: ParentNodeInterface where NodeType.ContainedItem==Contents, NodeType.LinkedItem==NodeType { // not meant to be instantiated or directly referenced
    typealias LinkedItem = NodeType;
    var next: NodeType?;

    init() {
        next = nil;
    }

    final func insertThisAfterMe(_ node: NodeType) {
        node.next = next;
        next = .some(node);
    }

    final func removeNodeAfterMe() -> NodeType? {
        guard let nextNode = next else {
            return nil;
        }

        let result = nextNode;

        next = result.next;
        result.next = nil;
        return nextNode;
    }
}

class Node<Contents>: ProtoNode<Contents, Node<Contents>>, ContainerNodeInterface {
    typealias ContainedItem = Contents;
    typealias NextItem = Node<Contents>;
    var contents: Contents;

    init(withContents: Contents) {
        contents = withContents;
        super.init();
    }
}

typealias ParentNode<Contents> = ProtoNode<Contents, Node<Contents>>;
```

But the Swift compiler, via Xcode, is complaining that `Type 'Node<Contents>' does not conform to protocol 'ParentNodeInterface'`. This makes no sense! And if I add explicit conformance to `ParentNodeInterface` to `Node`, then I get simultaneously that error and one of redundant conformance to the same protocol.

What is missing here?

Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125), Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

First, I would start with a simple linked-list Node type:

```
final class Node<Value> {
    let value: Value
    var next: Node<Value>?

    init(_ value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func insert(_ node: Node<Value>) {
        node.next = next
        next = node
    }

    func removeNext() -> Node<Value>? {
        guard let removedNode = next else { return nil }
        next = removedNode.next
        removedNode.next = nil
        return removedNode
    }
}
```

Then, you can add the concept that you describe: a pointer to "either a node...or to the linked list itself." When you see "or" in a description, that implies a sum type, which in Swift is an enum, either a pointer to the head of a (possibly empty) list, or a pointer to a node. Each has slightly different behaviors, which you manage with `switch`.

```
enum NodePointer<Value> {
    case head(Node<Value>?)
    case node(Node<Value>)

    mutating func insert(_ node: Node<Value>) {
        switch self {
        case .head(let n):
            self = .head(node)
            node.next = n
        case .node(let n):
            n.insert(node)
        }
    }

    mutating func removeNext() -> Node<Value>? {
        switch self {
        case .head(let n):
            self = .head(n?.next)
            return n
        case .node(let n):
            return n.removeNext()
        }
    }

    var pointee: Node<Value>? {
        switch self {
        case .head(let n): return n
        case .node(let n): return n
        }
    }
}
```

With that you would have an interface like:

```
var list = Node(1)
list.insert(Node(2))

var ptr = NodePointer.head(list)

ptr.insert(Node(1))
ptr.pointee?.next?.next?.value // 2
```

Note that the specific problem you ran into (that the compiler couldn't work out the conformance) I believe is a compiler bug, though I also believe it's one that's fixed on master currently. I haven't tested that out though. But I don't believe the protocol-based approach is correct for this problem.

Comment: I had an insight that the linked list object could be viewed as nothing more than a node with no associated contents since its is only a references to the first node, and therefore consider inserting at the top and inserting in the middle to be the same operation, applied on a different object. It may give more performance, by avoiding hard-to-predict branching. I might end up using this solution if it ends up being more performant, though.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by splitting ProtoNode into an initial declaration and an extension:

```
protocol ContainerNodeInterface: class {
    associatedtype ContainedItem;

    var contents: ContainedItem { get };
}

protocol ParentNodeInterface: class {
    associatedtype LinkedItem: ContainerNodeInterface;

    var next: LinkedItem? {get set};
}


class ProtoNode<Contents, NodeType: ContainerNodeInterface>: ParentNodeInterface where NodeType.ContainedItem==Contents { // not meant to be instantiated or directly referenced
    typealias LinkedItem = NodeType;
    var next: NodeType?;

    init() {
        next = nil;
    }
}

extension ProtoNode where NodeType: ParentNodeInterface, NodeType.LinkedItem==NodeType
{
    final func insertThisAfterMe(_ node: NodeType) {
        node.next = next;
        next = .some(node);
    }

    final func removeNodeAfterMe() -> NodeType? {
        guard let nextNode = next else {
            return nil;
        }

        let result = nextNode;

        next = result.next;
        result.next = nil;
        return nextNode;
    }
}

class Node<Contents>: ProtoNode<Contents, Node<Contents>>, ContainerNodeInterface {
    typealias ContainedItem = Contents;
    typealias NextItem = Node<Contents>;
    var contents: Contents;

    init(withContents: Contents) {
        contents = withContents;
        super.init();
    }
}

typealias ParentNode<Contents> = ProtoNode<Contents, Node<Contents>>;
```

I figure it helps the compiler break the dependency loop, where it has to determine whether Node, as a generic parameter, conforms to the protocol before it can determine the declaration is valid and consider the declared type, i.e. Node, as conforming to the protocol, but still it feels a bit silly for me to have to make this seemingly pointless extension declaration.

At the very least, the compiler could be slightly more helpful…